# Метод Reduce js

Tags: javascript

Начал изучать js и вот на этой задаче впал в ступор( Подскажите, пожалуйста, с какой стороны к ней подойти?

Нашему сервису необходимо рассчитать среднее время, проведенное в одной игре для каждого игрока, и получить общую сумму этих значений времени. Рассчитать время для каждого игрока можно, разделив его время (свойство playtime) на количество игр (свойство gamesPlayed).

Тесты

Объявленная переменная players
Значение переменной players – это массив объектов игроков
Объявлена ​​переменная totalAveragePlaytimePerGame
Значение переменной totalAveragePlaytimePerGame – это число 1023
Для переборки массива players используется метод reduce()

```
const players = [
  { name: "Mango", playtime: 1270, gamesPlayed: 4 },
  { name: "Poly", playtime: 469, gamesPlayed: 2 },
  { name: "Ajax", playtime: 690, gamesPlayed: 3 },
  { name: "Kiwi", playtime: 241, gamesPlayed: 1 },
];
// Change code below this line

const totalAveragePlaytimePerGame = players;
```

Comment: `players.reduce((acc, item) => acc += playtime / gamesPlayed;, 0);` и метод вернет вам сумму средних времен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод reduce позволяет в пройтись по всем элементам массива, выполнить какую-то функцию для каждого элемента массива и сохранить результат выполнения в переменную, которая будет доступна во всех итерациях

[Ссылка на спеку](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

В обучающих целях, давайте сначала рассмотрит более простой пример

Задача: *есть список банковских ячеек, нам нужно посчитать общую сумму. Список представляет из себя просто массив, где каждый элемент это кол-во "денег" в одной ячейке*

```js
const bank = [10, 11, 23, 0, 6];
let summOfBankCells = 0;

// С помощью reduce мы перебираем каждый элемент переменной bank и складываем значение элемент с итоговыми результатом
summOfBankCells = bank.reduce((acc, cell) => acc + cell, 0);
console.log(summOfBankCells);
```

В функцию, которая передается в метод reduce первым приходит аргумент, который будет аккумулировать значение между итерациями, вторым аргументом приходит элемент текущей итерации

> Важно! Функция переданная в reduce должна вернуть значение, которое и
> станет новым значением аккумулирующей переменной, если значение не
> вернуть, первый аргумент функции не изменится

Я не буду писать весь ответ, чтобы вы немного сами подумали, но подготовлю код, который будет работать, если его дополнить (как и в оригинальном задании, но чуть проще )

```js
const players = [
  { name: "Mango", playtime: 1270, gamesPlayed: 4 },
  { name: "Poly", playtime: 469, gamesPlayed: 2 },
  { name: "Ajax", playtime: 690, gamesPlayed: 3 },
  { name: "Kiwi", playtime: 241, gamesPlayed: 1 },
];

// Change code below this line
const totalAveragePlaytimePerGame = players.reduce((acc, item) => {
  return acc + /* здесь нужно посчитать среднее время игрока в текущей итерации */;
}, 0);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, все получилось!